# How to plot interactive and thematic maps in R?

Tags: r, dictionary, shapes

I have two files named `counties.rds` and `houses1990.rds`. The first one (`counties.rds`) includes conties of Caliornia state in the USA, and the second one (`houses1990.rds`) gives us some information about houses. I used the following codes to creat the variables `Cali_s` and `Houses-Cali` as follow:

```
Cali_s <- readRDS("counties.rds")
Cali_s <- raster::aggregate(California_shp, by = "NAME")
Houses-Cali <- readRDS("houses1990.rds")
```

To give you some information about `Cali_s` and `Houses-Cali`, the output of `dput(head(Cali_s))` and `dput(head(Houses_Cali))` are as follow:

```
dput(head(Cali_s))
structure(list(NAME = c("Alameda", "Alpine", "Amador", "Butte", 
"Calaveras", "Colusa")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

dput(head(Houses_Cali))
structure(list(houseValue = c(452600L, 358500L, 352100L, 341300L, 
342200L, 269700L), income = c(8.3252, 8.3014, 7.2574, 5.6431, 
3.8462, 4.0368), houseAge = c(41L, 21L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L), 
    rooms = c(880L, 7099L, 1467L, 1274L, 1627L, 919L), bedrooms = c(129L, 
    1106L, 190L, 235L, 280L, 213L), population = c(322L, 2401L, 
    496L, 558L, 565L, 413L), households = c(126L, 1138L, 177L, 
    219L, 259L, 193L), latitude = c(37.88, 37.86, 37.85, 37.85, 
    37.85, 37.85), longitude = c(-122.23, -122.22, -122.24, -122.25, 
    -122.25, -122.25)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I used the following codes to plot the below interactive map displaying the boundaries:

```
tmap_mode("view")
tm_shape(Cali_s) +tm_borders(alpha = 0.9,col ="BLUE")+ tm_text("NAME", size = 0.7)
```

[image]

- Considering the `houseValue` which is inside the `Houses-Cali` as the target (dependent) variable, I want to plot the following map (named map 1):

[image]

- Furthermore, using the `point-in-polygon` operation and the `mean` function, I want to merge the `Houses-Cali` object to `Cali_s`in order to plot the following thematic map (named map 2) of `houseValue` variable:

[image]

Could you please help me with how I can plot the two above maps (map 1 and map 2)?

Thank you in advance for your help